# Selenium With Python-Firefox always loading blank page

Tags: python, selenium

I've got an issue setting up and running Selenium with Python at first. 
My system- Windows 8.1, Python 3.4.4

When I try to call a browser with python code inside console or even running py doc with this particular code all I get-nothing but a blank page in browser. 
After some time I have errors in console.

```
    `C:\Python34\selenium\Tests>new1.py
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\selenium\Tests\new1.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser=webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_conne
ction.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.
py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.
py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile.
Profile Dir: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxr3qxv83 If you specified a lo
g_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
`
```

It would be really great if you may help me.

P.S. Pip version is the latest-8.1.2 
Firefox version 49.0.1

Here is the code where I've set the environment

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip.exe install selenium
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): selenium in c:\python3
4\lib\site-packages
```

It have been already installed before

Small update,guys

I have created Firefox profile especially for selenium tests. But I have the same problem with exception again.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>>> fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefo
x/Profiles/2byxc9l6.selenium')
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_conne
ction.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.
py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.
py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile.
Profile Dir: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpe1dfmxt_\webdriver-py-profilec
opy If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for d
etails.

>>>
```

What I did wrong if selenium is searching PATH in another directory?

P.S. Selenium version is 2.53.6. Firefox is 49.0.1

Comment: Post your code here with correct format please.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your FF profile. Show us the code where you set up the webdriver. And version info of Selenium/Firefox. Does C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxr3qxv83 exist and is it a valid readable profile?

Comment: @Olexiy without the source code it's difficult to understand your problem.

Comment: I don't know the code of `new1.py` but you seem to use the constructor without parameters. FirefoxDriver appararently expects a profile in this directory C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxr3qxv83 and fails to load it (not existent, not readable, ...) To find out more about firefox profiles, read here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with loading a Firefox profile. In order to avoid that, you should use a **custom profile** for your tests.

Create a custom profile: Close all instances of Firefox and then start it from command line with `firefox -P`. Follow the steps to create a profile with some meaningful name (like 'selenium') and make sure you the directory where the profile is saved. Details are explained [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).

Replace the code in `new1.py` to create a firefox driver instance with custom profile, e.g. if your profile is located in folder "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\cmx3h2wi.selenium", replace the line `browser=webdriver.Firefox()` with this (note the forward slashes even on Windows, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095294/using-the-default-firefox-profile-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/cmx3h2wi.selenium')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
```

That way FirefoxDriver should load a profile exclusively for your selenium tests.

Comment: I solved a problem by downgrading Firefox to 46 version. Thank's, guys, for your help!