# Open browser with selenium like manualy

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to open browser with selenium with

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

But, when i did it, it open a blank browser without my personalized on firefox. So, have anyway to open Firefox with personalized like manualy open firefox? Thanks!

Comment: What personalization you want ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What profile does Selenium WebDriver use by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031253/what-profile-does-selenium-webdriver-use-by-default)

Comment: @furas but it is in Java

Comment: check in Python - it should has similar function to choose profile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the default firefox profile with selenium webdriver in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095294/using-the-default-firefox-profile-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the personalized firefox profile before starting the firefox browser.
Below is the code:

```
/* Creating an instance of FirefoxProfile */
firefox_Profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\abcd\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\96e5mzk0.Default')

/* Passing the firefox profile in the webdriver*/
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_Profile)
```

Comment: It work, can open profile with this, but it still cannot load page with `browser.get("http://www.python.org")`