# Python Selenium getting started error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have updated to Selenium 3. I have set gecko in PATH but continue to get the error. Firefox starts up but then no action for a few moments and Firefox closes (i assume a time out).Any incite would be greatly appreciated!

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Paul\Documents\python selenium\python_org_search.py", line 4, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 78, in **init**
>       self.binary, timeout)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 49, in **init**
>       self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
>       self._wait_until_connectable()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 106, in _wait_until_connectable
>       % (self.profile.path))
>   WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: c:\users\paul\appdata\local\temp\tmphptyx9 If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

EDIT:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us.

Comment: check the geckodriver log file to see what does it say.

Comment: Try changing your driver variable like this: driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='your geckodriver.exe path')

Comment: I have reverted to using Chrome instead and its working perfect!

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095294/using-the-default-firefox-profile-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python